# Nesting IFS statement inside DATEDIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, datediff, ifs

I am nesting an IF statement inside a DATEDIF to determine employee tenure. I am trying to write the formula in such a way that pulls the termination date if the cell is not blank, but uses today's date if the cell is blank.

Here is the formula I wrote but it is coming back with a #NAME? error.

=DATEDIF([@[Hire Date]],IFS([@[Exit Date]]<>””,[@[Exit Date]],[@[Exit Date]]="",TODAY()),"M")

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some sort of strange quotes `””` in there.

Try this.

```
=DATEDIF([@[Hire Date]],IF([@[Exit Date]]<>"",[@[Exit Date]],TODAY()),"M")
```

Note, I don't think you need the nested IF - the above formula will give the same answer as your formula, once the strange quotes are replaced of course.

Comment: So I tried the formula you recommended and I’m still getting a #Name? Error. The <>”” means if a cell isn’t blank and =“” means the cell is blank based on what I found online.